# Structured data events with multiple startDate in JSON-LD

Tags: date, schema.org, json-ld

My site having classes with multiple start dates, i.e., class will be scheduled today, tomorrow and day after tomorrow. I want to show events for this class.

I have used following JSON-LD code but it is picking last date in list.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
            [{
              "@context" : "http://schema.org",
              "@type" : "EducationEvent",
              "name" : "leed-exam-prep",
              "startDate" : "Thursday, September 8, 2016<br />Friday, September 9, 2016",
              "url": "https://www.example.com/class/leed-exam-prep/leed-green-associate-exam-prep",
              "location" : {
                "@type" : "Place",
                 "name" : "WI - Madison",
                 "address" : "WI - Madison"
              }
            }]
```

How can I use multiple start dates for same class?

Answer (score 2):

The [`startDate` property](http://schema.org/startDate) expects a [`Date`](http://schema.org/Date) or a [`DateTime`](http://schema.org/DateTime) value (both according to ISO 8601).

So instead of `Thursday, September 8, 2016` and `Friday, September 9, 2016`, the values should be `2016-09-08` and `2016-09-09`.

---

Providing multiple `startDate` values is possible by [using an array](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81081/17633):

```
"startDate": ["2016-09-08", "2016-09-09"]
```

But you should probably not do this in your case. The [`Event` type](http://schema.org/Event) (and [`EducationEvent`](http://schema.org/EducationEvent) is a more specific `Event`) represents a single event. So you should provide multiple `EducationEvent` nodes, each with its own `startDate`.

You could, for example, have one super event (representing the class) with multiple [`subEvent`](http://schema.org/subEvent) values (representing the class sessions).